# Как добавить строку в GridPane (javafx) по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: java, javafx, gridpane

Есть на форме GridPane, есть на форме Button. Нужно в GridPane создавать новую строку по нажатию на Button. Можно ли такое вообще сделать?
К слову всё GUI сделано в Scene Builder'е, в том числе и Button и GridPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FXML
private void onButtonAction() {
    addRow();
}

/* или 
@FXML
Buttion button;

@FXML
private void initialize() {
    button.setOnAction( ae -> {
        addRow();
    } );
}
*/

private void addRow() {
    gridPane.add( someNode0, columnIndex0, rowIndex );
    gridPane.add( someNode1, columnIndex1, rowIndex );
    //etc
}
```